# Bootstrap 4 - Fixed/Sticky Headers for Table on a Tab

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple Bootstrap 4 page with multiple tabs on the page. Each tab has a different table, some of which have a large number of rows. I would now like to make the table header on each tab fixed/sticky so that it doesn't scroll as the user scrolls the page down.

Here's an example of my page with a table on the first tab:

```css
th {
  background: white;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" width="165" height="36" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Management</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="jobs.php?action=showall">Jobs List</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="jobsSearch.php">Search Jobs</a>
        </div>
      </li>





      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-7">

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td width=35%>Ref Number:</td>
        <td width=80%>123456</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Acme Corp Pty Ltd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Job Number:</td>
        <td>5521236987452</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>21 Jump St, Beverley Hills 90210</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Client:</td>
        <td>Sony Pty Ltd</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>State:</td>
        <td>CA </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Inspection Date:</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    </table>


  </div>

</div>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="projectTabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="Contacts-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Contacts" role="tab" aria-controls="Contacts" aria-selected="true">Contacts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="Contractors-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Contractors" role="tab" aria-controls="Contractors" aria-selected="false">Contractors</a>
  </li>

</ul>


<div class="tab-content" id="Tabs">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="Contacts" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Contacts">



    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Code</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr id="211140">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5281"> Jaxon Copeley</a></td>

          <td>Senior Designer</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="212265">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM4102"> Sean Dacey</a></td>

          <td>Associate</td>
          <td>1687</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="212364">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5448"> Nathan Giffen</a></td>

          <td>Senior Designer</td>
          <td>273.8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="212312">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM6256"> Tristan Godson</a></td>

          <td>Project Designer </td>
          <td>85.75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="207542">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM6123"> Anthony McAulay</a></td>

          <td>Designer</td>
          <td>566.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="207990">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5466"> Gabriella Schofield</a></td>

          <td>Senior Designer</td>
          <td>107</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="213479">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM6513"> Hayden Giblin</a></td>

          <td>Creative Designer</td>
          <td>60</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="208423">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5313"> Archer Doolan</a></td>

          <td>Associate</td>
          <td>487.9</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="208468">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM4330"> Taylah Hutcheon</a></td>

          <td>Senior Associate</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="212645">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM0038"> Hayley Hodgson</a></td>

          <td>Director</td>
          <td>37</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="214303">
          <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM4237"> Henry Powell</a></td>

          <td></td>
          <td>9</td>
        </tr>


      </tbody>
    </table>




  </div>
```

Is it possible to have the headers on the tabs fixed so they are visible as you scroll down the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `position:sticky` property on `th` elements for this.

If you have an additional fixed element on your page (like a fixed navbar), set the `top` property to the height of this element, so it sticks to the bottom of it:

```css
th {
        background: white;
        position: sticky;
        top: 60px; /* this is the distance from the top of the viewport your element will 'stick' to. */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-7">
      
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr>
              <td width=35%>Ref Number:</td>
              <td width=80%>123456</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name:</td>
              <td>Acme Corp Pty Ltd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Job Number:</td>
              <td>5521236987452</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Address:</td>
              <td>21 Jump St, Beverley Hills 90210</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Client:</td>
              <td>Sony Pty Ltd</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>State:</td>
              <td>CA </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Inspection Date:</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
      
          </table>
      
      
        </div>
      
      </div>
      
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="projectTabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="Contacts-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Contacts" role="tab" aria-controls="Contacts" aria-selected="true">Contacts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="Contractors-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#Contractors" role="tab" aria-controls="Contractors" aria-selected="false">Contractors</a>
        </li>
      
      </ul>
      
      
      <div class="tab-content" id="Tabs">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="Contacts" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Contacts">
      
      
      
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Code</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
      
              <tr id="211140">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5281"> Jaxon Copeley</a></td>
      
                <td>Senior Designer</td>
                <td>8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="212265">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM4102"> Sean Dacey</a></td>
      
                <td>Associate</td>
                <td>1687</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="212364">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5448"> Nathan Giffen</a></td>
      
                <td>Senior Designer</td>
                <td>273.8</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="212312">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM6256"> Tristan Godson</a></td>
      
                <td>Project Designer </td>
                <td>85.75</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="207542">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM6123"> Anthony McAulay</a></td>
      
                <td>Designer</td>
                <td>566.2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="207990">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5466"> Gabriella Schofield</a></td>
      
                <td>Senior Designer</td>
                <td>107</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="213479">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM6513"> Hayden Giblin</a></td>
      
                <td>Creative Designer</td>
                <td>60</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="208423">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM5313"> Archer Doolan</a></td>
      
                <td>Associate</td>
                <td>487.9</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="208468">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM4330"> Taylah Hutcheon</a></td>
      
                <td>Senior Associate</td>
                <td>5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="212645">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM0038"> Hayley Hodgson</a></td>
      
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>37</td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="214303">
                <td><a href="view.php?action=viewDetails&ID=PM4237"> Henry Powell</a></td>
      
                <td></td>
                <td>9</td>
              </tr>
      
      
            </tbody>
          </table>
      
      
      
      
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks for that. I just realised I forgot to include the navbar. I've updated my snippet with your CSS and my navbar and you can see it's not working with the navbar present. Any suggestions to get this working with the navbar here?

Comment: You just need to change the `top` property to the height of your navbar, in this case 60 pixels: Replace `top:0px;` with `top:60px;`